# Нужно разделить переменную на две части в python

Tags: python-3.x, переменные, строки

У меня например есть переменная `str = (7878, 14)` и мне её нужно разделить на две переменных, первая должна равняется 7878 ,а вторая 14 (естественно от значения первой переменой).
Пишу на python.
Можете помочь?

Comment: индексы исползуйте

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я понял, Вам нужно разделить кортеж (tuple) на две переменных. Лучше сделать так:

```py
str = (7878, 14)
a, b = str
```

В а будет первый элемент, в b - второй.
Ещё можно **(но не нужно)** вот так:

```py
str = (7878, 14)
a = str[0]
b = str[1]
```

Comment: большое спасибо помогло

Answer (score 0):

```
newArray = (7878, 14)
arr1 = newArray[0]
arr2 = newArray[1]
print(arr1) #>>> 7878
print(arr2) #>>> 14
```

Это не переменная, это массив. Почитай [документацию](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp)

Comment: Это не массив, это кортеж. Читайте документацию.

Comment: извиняюсь, спасибо большое